# Make notification when app is closed

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

I have separate API for my Android app and I'm using Restful services for connecting my API. For now, I need to show notification even app is closed by the way of connecting my backend using the Restful method because all notification messages are, will get only the way of calling the API.
What is the correct implementation to solve this problem?

Comment: in the title you wrote that you want to show notification when the app gets closed, but in question you write that you want it also when the app is open, and just don't want the notification to disappear when the app is closed. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create background services then you can call your API like

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   //here you can call your API

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If you want some time interval then you can call your API, inside the post delayed method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). It allows you to send push notifications to your app from your backend through google servers.

Comment: How can I identify different users, because notifications will vary every particular user?

Comment: Evrery device has its own id so you can determine which one you want to notificate

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notifications for this. Integrate with FCM that will allow your app to get notification from backend even when app is closed.

You can follow below links for this

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/